# RDLC matrix totals with group filters

Tags: vba, reporting-services, grouping, rdlc

I have a matrix with result as follow:
[image]

There is a `TOP N` filter applied to column group. I want to calculate correct values for `Rest` column. Currently my code return all `Rest` as 0 because I am calculating `Total-Sum(Value, "RowGroupName")` and it seems it does take into account filtered `colgr4` and `colgr5`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use custom code in your expressions

In your report add the following custom code

```
Dim Total = 0

Function SetRestValue (Byval v AS Double) AS Double

Total = Total + v
Return v

End function

Function GetRestValue () AS Double
Dim temp AS Double

temp = Total
Total = 0
Return temp

End Function
```

The code uses two functions:
`SetRestValue` executes and calculates the total for the visible(unfiltered) cells

`GetRestValue` returns the visible cell total in order to deduct it from the whole row total, and sets the total to zero.

Now on your matrix:

Set your matrix value to the following expression
`=Code.SetRestValue(Sum(Fields!value.Value))`

Set the rest column expression to `= SUM(Fields!value.Value) - Code.GetRestValue()`

[image]

[image]